# How to prevent a duplication of collecting logs in ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm using an AWS integration on elastic agent to gather logs from AWS cloudwatch.

In AWS integration policy, start position is "beginning"(default value).

When a server where an AWS integration is installed downs for a while and starts up later, AWS integration always gathers log from beginning position on cloud-watch log group.

I stopped AWS agent in elastic search and started later. Then, agent started to get logs from 'beginning position' of cloud watch log group.

How can I get logs from the position which agent stopped at?

I don't want to set start position to "end". It might lose data for down periods.

How can I get logs from the position which agent stopped at?